# Android: self written RotationAnimation for speedometer - performance?

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, animation, image-rotation

I'm a step further with my speedometer, but I'm not that satisfied with my "solution".
I created my own View for displaying my Speedometer. The View extends ImageView and displays the speedometer (without the needle). When the speed is going to be updated, the needle will rotate to the current angle and the View invalidates. Now my problem is, that the needle kind of "jumps" (p.e. from 50km/h to 100km/h). Now I'd like to draw a smooth Animation over that.
A RotationAnimation rotates my whole speedometer, this is why I decided to write a new Thread which animates the needle with 30FPS and therefore calls invalidate() 30times per second. That works, but I allways have that additional Thread in the Background. When I later have more instruments than the speedometer, there are lots more Threads. Now my first Question: How performant is my solution? How many threads could be handled per Application?

My second idea is to use a SurfaceView for the needle, where I could use a RotationAnimation. But I'm not sure, whether it is possible, to show the current speed on a digital Display while the needle rotates. (p.e.: the needle animates from 50km/h to 100km/h, so it is important, that the speed on the digital display is always the same, the needle points at, and not that it always shows 50, until the needle reaches the 100, and then the digital display jumps instantly to 100).

I hope you could help me with some nice tips.
Help would be greatly appreceated

Answer (score 0):

you could try to implement the Observer/Observable pattern in combination with a presenter. your "current speed" caluclation logic would update the "view-model" object which implements the observable pattern and is registered on the presenter(observer). now with every update the  presenter is notified and it invalidates/repaints your view. On top you could add a"cooldown" to the presenter which prevents updates to be propagated more often than x times per second.

that would scale to whatever amount of signals and pipe all logic through your presenter class.

Comment: okay, i could use the observer-pattern to refresh the data, but how would that help me with my animation? I didn't get your hint with the presenter. sorry

Comment: if you have a control logic inbetween your real data and your view you could pass a "from - to" animaiton to the view using the view animation framework: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html

Comment: okay, thank you for this information. But as far as I understand, I'm back at my basic problem: speedometer animates with the needle, not only the needle: **quote** _So, if you have a TextView object, you can move, rotate, grow, or shrink the text. If it has a background image, the background image will be transformed along with the text._